# Javascript routing to individual pages with IDs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, routes, card

I'm currently trying to route specific cards to their own pages. I would like to write a function which takes a string literal and inserts it into an individual_card_page.html using javascript, rather than hard-coding a page for each individual card. However, I'm not sure what a good way to approach this is, and I heard using the ID of each card is a possibility. What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: you can use a tag for navigating `<a href="./details.html?id=${id}">Show details</a>` and then inside yout details.js file, on document.ready() you should be able to get the route params and extract your ID
`let params = new window.URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 let id= params.get('id');`

Comment: I see. I haven't learned about this before. Is there a resource where I can get more information or examples about this? This sounds extremely similar to the use of props in React